# Binary Serializer not working except for first time

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

Why would this code only work when it's called for the first time(adds the first element). In the consequent calls, the file stays the same, containing only one user

```
        public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(PATH_TO_LOGINS, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        List<User> users=new List<User>();
        if (stream.Length > 0)
            users = (List<User>) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        users.Add(user);
        formatter.Serialize(stream,users);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please show your actual code. `users` here is a local variable that you don't return, so obviously it can only hold the one user you add.

Comment: it is my actual code, I add a valid user object each time

Comment: Surley there is a more effecient way of doing this

Comment: Okay, then, but it's a local variable that you re-create each time.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError is there any problem?

Comment: Do `stream.Position = 0` before you call `formatter.Serialize(...)`.

Comment: I wouldn't use the BinaryFormatter to persist data to file. If ever something changes in your `User` class, you won't be able to load it anymore,. Also, the format quiet verbose although binary.

Comment: @Dejan : That behaviour can be controlled. One could apply the `OptionalField` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `stream.Position = 0` before you perform the serialization. That way you start writing from the very beginning of the file when you serialize it.

If you don't set it to 0 you'll start writing from the end of the file and forward, since it's where the `FileStream`'s position currently is after you performed the deserialization.

```
users.Add(user);
stream.Position = 0;
formatter.Serialize(stream,users);
```